# Convert latitude longitude to a custom soccer pitch XY coordinates

Tags: gps

I have come across various solutions to this problem but i have not been able to implement anything that is close to accurate. I have a data file that consist of GPS locations data. My aim is to plot this data on a 110X68 soccer pitch. The data file also consist the GPS coordinates for the corners of the soccer pitch. I need to get this done in python.

[In this image the pitch corners have latitude longitude and the XY coordinates. We have the GPS coords for the player and want to convert them to XY coordinates with respect to the pitch dimensions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cyhoz.png)

Comment: Use proj4 (or any other python geographic libraries [which will include it anyway]). Convert to a metric coordinate (so a x,y coordinate system with lengths instead of angles). E.g. one UTM projection for the region. So now you have metric coordinates. Then it is just a coordinate rotation and ev. scaling, if you do not like meters). You need to do it yourself (you will learn a lot, and also how to check). It is inevitable that you will do errors (also if you copy code), and if you never did yourself you will go in a nightmare of debugging (aka debugging the wrong parts).

Comment: Thanks for the guidance @GiacomoCatenazzi. Have you worked in proj4? If so I  have a question. How do I set the fence in pyproj call for my pitch to be able to get the XY within that area.

Comment: See e.g. https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/298929/converting-lat-lon-to-x-y-coordinates-with-pyproj and  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Transverse_Mercator_coordinate_system to find the zone

Comment: I think I am not getting it. How will these zone help me get the XY coordinate within my pitch dimensions ?